# Extract rows from file 1 based on range of columns from file 2

Tags: awk, range

I have two files

File 1:

```
chrom   chromStart      chromEnd   clinSign    geneId  rcvAcc  hgvsCod hgvsProt
chr1    930187  930188      VUS  SNV      SAMD11   RCV001050361    NM_152486.3:c.106G>A    NP_689699.2:p.Ala36Thr
 chr1    939398  939446     Benign  deletion       SAMD11   RCV000948524    NM_152486.2:c.683_706+24delCCCCTCATCACCTCCCCAGCCACGGTGAGGACCCACCCTGGCATGATC
```

File 2:

```
CHROM   POS  REF  ALT  FILTER     GT     BD    
chr1    1609489 AAC     A       PASS    0/1     FP
chr1    930188 T       G       LowGQ  0/1     FP
chr1    939400 TGC     T       PASS    0/1     FP
```

I'm trying to query file 2 based on CHROM:POS (1st & 2nd column) against the range of the first three columns from File 1 (chrom:chromStart:ChromEnd) and then have an output

```
chrom   chromStart      chromEnd     clinSign         geneId  rcvAcc  hgvsCod hgvsProt  CHROM        POS  REF  ALT  FILTER      GT     BD     
chr1    930187  930188         VUS  SNV     SAMD11   RCV001050361    NM_152486.3:c.106G>A    NP_689699.2:p.Ala36Thr  chr1    930188 T       G       LowGQ  0/1     FP
chr1    939398  939446     Benign  deletion        SAMD11   RCV000948524    NM_152486.2:c.683_706+24delCCCCTCATCACCTCCCCAGCCACGGTGAGGACCCACCCTGGCATGATC  chr1    939400 TGC     T       PASS    0/1     FP
```

So far I have tried

```
awk '
NR==FNR{ start[$1] = $2; end[$1] = $3; next }
(FNR==1) || ( ($1 in start) && ($2 >= start[$1]) && ($2 <= end[$1]) )
' file1 file2> test.txt
```

```
awk 'FNR == NR { low[$1] = $2; high[$1] = $3; next }
>     $2 > low[$1] && $2 < high[$1] { print }' file1 file2 > test.txt
```

but both result in an empty file as output

any suggestions are appreciated. thank you

Comment: There can only be one entry in an array for a particular key. So the second line of File 1 is overwriting the start and end arrays from the first line.

Comment: You need to store multiple ranges for each `chrom` value, and test all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == 1 { hdr = $0 }
NR == FNR {
    c = ++cnt[$1]
    begs[$1,c] = $2
    ends[$1,c] = $3
    vals[$1,c] = $0
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    print hdr, $0
    next
}
{
    for (c=1; c<=cnt[$1]; c++) {
        beg = begs[$1,c]
        end = ends[$1,c]
        if ( (beg <= $2) && ($2 <= end) ) {
            print vals[$1,c], $0
            next
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
chrom   chromStart      chromEnd   clinSign    geneId  rcvAcc  hgvsCod hgvsProt CHROM   POS  REF  ALT  FILTER     GT     BD
chr1    930187  930188      VUS  SNV      SAMD11   RCV001050361    NM_152486.3:c.106G>A    NP_689699.2:p.Ala36Thr chr1    930188 T       G       LowGQ  0/1     FP
 chr1    939398  939446     Benign  deletion       SAMD11   RCV000948524    NM_152486.2:c.683_706+24delCCCCTCATCACCTCCCCAGCCACGGTGAGGACCCACCCTGGCATGATC chr1    939400 TGC     T       PASS    0/1     FP
```

If you can have multiple ranges match for a given chrom then just remove the final `next` statement - it's only there for efficiency if there's always just 1 match.

Answer (score 2):

```
> cat test.awk    

FNR==NR {
    if (NR==1) { title = $0; next }
    positions[$1] = positions[$1]" "$2
    r[$1,$2] = $0
    next
}

FNR==1 { print $0, title; next }

{
    split(positions[$1], p)
    for (i in p)
        if (p[i]>=$2 && p[i]<=$3) {
            print $0, r[$1,p[i]]
            next
        }
}
```

test

```
> awk -f test.awk file2 file1

chrom   chromStart      chromEnd   clinSign    geneId  rcvAcc  hgvsCod hgvsProt CHROM   POS  REF  ALT  FILTER     GT     BD    
chr1    930187  930188      VUS  SNV      SAMD11   RCV001050361    NM_152486.3:c.106G>A    NP_689699.2:p.Ala36Thr chr1    930188 T       G       LowGQ  0/1     FP
 chr1    939398  939446     Benign  deletion       SAMD11   RCV000948524    NM_152486.2:c.683_706+24delCCCCTCATCACCTCCCCAGCCACGGTGAGGACCCACCCTGGCATGATC chr1    939400 TGC     T       PASS    0/1     FP
```

First pass, we store positions in a pseudo-2d array, which is actually a string with space separated numbers, indices are the first fields. At the second pass, we split it to numbers and we do the check per row.

---

Edit: Thanks to Ed Morton for the help to fix it.

Here we parse the files in the opposite order than Ed's answer, but again the last `next` statement can be removed in case we can have multiple matches for the same "chrom" and we want to print all of them.